# How do I use java streams to group by object attribute's attribute?...two levels deep?

Tags: java

So, for example consider these two objects:

```
class MyObject {
    Integer Id;
    MyObjectInner myObjectInner;
}

class MyObjectInner {
    Integer Id:
    String attributeToGroupBy;
}
```

If I wanted to group the a list of MyObjects by Id, I would do something like:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> myObjectsPerId = 
    myObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getId));
```

But what if I needed to group by MyObject::MyObjectInner::AttributeToGroupBy, how would I do that?

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.myObjectInner.attributeToGroupBy)`

Comment: Thanks for answering Johannes!  That worked!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a getId() method in you MyObject class for this to work.

```
class MyObject {
    Integer Id;
    MyObjectInner myObjectInner;

    public MyObject(){}

    public Integer getId() { return this.Id; }
}
```

Then, you could create your map with :

```
Map<Object, List<MyObject>> myObjectsPerId = 
    myObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getId()));
```